# Good English translation for French military term "Baptême du feu"

Tags: french, military

In French, "Baptême du feu" is a military term that refers to the first combat experience of a new recruit.

Literally translated, it would be "Fire Baptism" or "Baptism of Fire". I don't think an English audience would understand what's meant by that though. It seems that "Baptism by fire" also has strong religious connotations in English.

What is the English military term for this?

Is there a good English translation that maintains some of the "poetic" characteristics of the French version?

Comment: Does the French phrase *not* resonate even a little with Matthew 3.11 or Luke 3.16?

Comment: "Baptism of fire" is a common English phrase, and will be understood by everybody.

Comment: Closely related is ***trial by fire***.

Comment: @BrianDonovan Not everybody is a Christian.

Comment: baptism literally means "full immersion" so agnostics and atheists can use the phrase happily.

Answer (score 21):

The expression is used in English also:

> - Phrase [baptism of fire](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=baptism) "a soldier's first experience of battle" (1857) translates French baptême de feu.

(Etymonline)

***[Baptism of fire](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/baptism+of+fire)***:

> - A severe ordeal or test, especially an initial one, as in This audition would be Robert's baptism of fire. This term transfers the original religious rite of baptism, whereby holiness is imparted, to various kinds of ordeal. ***At first it signified the death of martyrs at the stake, and in 19th-century France it was used for a soldier's first experience of combat.***

(AHD)

also ***baptism by fire***:

> - ***In the military usage, a [baptism by fire](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baptism_by_fire#) refers to a soldier's first time in battle.*** The Catholic Encyclopedia, and writers such as John Deedy, state that the term in a military sense entered the English language in 1822 as a translation of the French phrase baptême du feu.
>     From military usage the term has extended into many other areas in relation to an initiation into a new role - for example the directorship of an arts festival.

(Wikipedia)

Note that the common current meaning of the expression is:

[Baptism of/by fire](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/dizionario/inglese/a-baptism-of-by-fire)
​

> a very difficult first experience of something:
>   - *I was given a million-dollar project to manage in my first month - it was a real baptism of fire.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

> Currently it is used more loosely for any difficult first encounter.

(AHD)

Comment: According to [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=baptism+of+fire%2Cbaptism+by+fire&year_start=1800&year_end=2017&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbaptism%20of%20fire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbaptism%20by%20fire%3B%2Cc0), _baptism of fire_ is significantly more common than _baptism by fire_.

Comment: @Josh Can I suggest 'The expression is also often used in English without invoking any religious overtones'?

Comment: What @EdwinAshworth said, and, I have only ever heard _Baptism by Fire_.  I have also heard it used in many non-military contexts such as taking on a job duty that you aren't trained/experienced in.

Comment: @TonyK Be careful with a general Ngram on that, because *baptism of fire* is a specific Christian religious term.

Comment: @TonyK: [This ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=baptism+of+fire%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbaptism+by+fire%3Aeng_us_2012%2Cbaptism+of+fire%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Cbaptism+by+fire%3Aeng_gb_2012%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbaptism%20of%20fire%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbaptism%20by%20fire%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbaptism%20of%20fire%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cbaptism%20by%20fire%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) shows that while that is true, the difference is less for AmE than it is for BrE.

Comment: @TonyK I suspect in general use today that *by* fire is more common. An actual Google Books search (not Ngrams) limiting to the 21st century shows slightly more for the *by* version than the *of* version, and a web search is much more skewed in favor of *by* (you have to click through pages of results to see how many there actually are—155 for *of* and 171 for *by* with my Google Books search, and 173 vs 407 for the web).

Answer (score -2):

Baptism of fire is a common expression in English (as is trial by fire, which is not connected at all). Neither is used with any religious connotation nowadays. A baptism of fire is having to perform any difficult task for the first time without training or experience. Baptism BY fire is nonsense but I wouldn't be surprised if people use it. I've never heard it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you provide some argument for your claim that *baptism **by** fire* is **nonsense**? That is the only component of your answer that differentiates it from what has already been posted on this page.